# Javascript get("").textContent

Tags: javascript

Estou tendo um pequeno problema com o `get("").textContent` aparece

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: get is not defined
```

o código é esse

```
get("Machineamount").textContent = jogo.Maquinas.toNumber()
```

O `.toNumber` é por que eu estou usando ExpantaNum.js, que permite com que tenha números maiores

print pra facilitar o entendimento

[[image: código1]

eu botei em uma função só pra eu poder mexer com ajuda do console

[image: o html]

o site quando carrega ( não fiz mt css nem nada )

[image: o site]

Edit:
Eu dei uma burrada
isso é pq eu tava usando código que tinha sido "ajudado" para o developer de outro código usar ele ( eu só tinha testado naquilo que era fazer mod de 1 jogo ) então eu achei que era get

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: eu acho que eu melhorei, se não, pode me falar como melhorar a pergunta?

Comment: Olá Cris Foi você quem criou a tal função get()? Porque nativamente ela não existe.

Comment: Eu demorei muito tempo pra descobrir que ela não existe

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Faz assim ó:

```js
 document.getElementById("Machineamount").textContent = "o que vc quiser"
```

Espero ter ajudado ! :D

Comment: muito obrigado, realmente ajudou